# My postgresql database doesn't persist between docker runs

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am learning docker and postgresql and I have problem with persisting data between the re-runs of the app.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    external: true
```

I run my project with `docker-compose up -d` go with `docker-compose exec web python3 manage.py migrate` but after I go `docker-compose down` and I run the containers I have to migrate again. It's really bothersome. Can someone help, please?

Comment: Can you verify that the database configuration in your application is in fact connecting to the `db` container, and not for example an embedded SQLite database?  Do you see the tables using a separate SQL client tool like `psql`?  The database volume configuration seems correct to me.

Comment: Try add env variable `PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` to `db`. What is your operating systems? Can you also add `db` container logs when? I never had issue like this so it looks pretty strange and it looks more like some system issue that is causing docker to lose data

Comment: I have already solved this, but thanks for your contribution ✌️

Answer (score 0):

```
volumes:
  postgres_data:
    external: true
```

Do you know what is does? As far as I know if you create a volume with command: `docker volume create` you can reference it in your compose. So if you don't know its usage this is what causing the problem. As I guess you didn't create a volume.
So for it to work properly just remove line `external: true` and let docker do the management of your volume. And as long as you don't use `docker compose down --volumes` your data persists.

Comment: That's what I tried before. The helpful response is the one given by @hmn Falahi.
And yes I used `docker volume create` before I set the `docker-compose.yml`  `volumes` `external`. This was the main reason why I tried the external setting, because without it, the data was lost each time I used `docker-compose down`.
You made a lot of assumptions writing your answer. Perhaps verify them in the comments next time :)